# Retrieving an identifier from timed-out std::future?

Tags: c++, multithreading, future

I have an async executor that sends requests to a server with an id. The server performs the request and the executor will be able to identify the work item `promise` from this same id value in the response. Requests may time out. In such case, I want the executor to drop the ID of this request completely. However, I don't know how identify this promise when the future timed out and there is no ID from the server.

I'm posting a simplified example for brevity.

```
struct Executor {
    std::map<work_id_t, std::promise<Result>> work_items;
};

// run requests asynchronously
std::future<Result> Executor::post_work(Request r, work_id_t id) {
    work_items[id] = std::promise<Result>();
    do_request(w);
    return work_items[id].get_future();
}

// called when a requests finishes (the server supplies the id)
void Executor::work_finished(work_id_t id, Result r) {
    work_items[id].set_value(r);
    work_items.erase(id);
}

// ...

Executor e;
auto ft = e.post_work(Request("foo"));    
auto wait_result = ft.wait_for(timeout_value);
if (wait_result == std::future_status::timeout) {
    e.remove_item(???); // what can I pass here?
}
```

How can I implement the `remove_item` function when a timeout happens? Alternatively, how can I change my design to allow a similar mechanism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the interface you supplied it seems the `work_id_t` is available in the call to `Executor::post_work`.

As such, since the caller needs the id in the event of a timeout, just return both the future and the id from `post_work`:

Perhaps wrap it in a struct such as:

```
struct Work {
    std::future<Result> ft;
    work_id_t id;
};
```

If you return a `Work` instance from `Executor::post_work`, you can then wait on the future, and in the event of a timeout, use the id to remove the item

```
Work w = ...
auto wait_result = w.ft.wait_for(timeout_value);
if (wait_result == std::future_status::timeout) {
    e.remove_item(w.id);
}
```

**In the context of your example:**

```
struct Executor {
    std::map<work_id_t, std::promise<Result>> work_items;
};

struct Work {
    std::future<Result> ft;
    work_id_t id;
};

// run requests asynchronously
Work Executor::post_work(Request r, work_id_t id) {
    work_items[id] = std::promise<Result>();
    do_request(w);
    return { work_items[id].get_future(), id };
}

// called when a requests finishes (the server supplies the id)
void Executor::work_finished(work_id_t id, Result r) {
    work_items[id].set_value(r);
    work_items.erase(id);
}

// ...

Executor e;
Work w = e.post_work(Request("foo"));    
auto wait_result = w.ft.wait_for(timeout_value);
if (wait_result == std::future_status::timeout) {
    e.remove_item(w.id);
}
```